# how can I use google spreadsheet as a database for real time ops

Tags: javascript, html, spreadsheet

I'm new in web applications and developing.

I m trying to develop an application that can take GPS coordinates with HTML5 geolocation. And I can show the point in the map.

But from this point I want to develop smtg similar to google latitude and I want to save the coordinates of the members in Database. And I want this database an online database.

After saving this coordinates I will make their history lines and the members will see their places and also their histories.

I'm using HTML5 and javascript. Is this possible to access and to use spreadsheet as an online database with or without javascript. OR  how can I do this process with an other option(both language and database).

Thank you for everything...

UPDATE:

// I am using the code below and I wanna save the enlem and boylam variables to spreadsheet and  want to receive this data afterwards to show on the map the history of the man I fallow. And also for 4 or 5 people at the same time as a tracking people application.
 Is it possible to do this work on spreadshhet or do I have to use a database for this.

And the problem is ıs there any possibility to send or receive data from spreadsheet in javascript or as tobia said I can only handle this problem with server side languages....

Thank you for  everything...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/css/hidden.css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Neredeyim?</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/interface.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">

<article>

</article>

<script type="text/javascript">

function success(position) {
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '100%';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';

  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);


  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var en=coords.lat();
  var enlem=en.toFixed(2);// latitude variable
  var boy=coords.lng();
  var boylam=boy.toFixed(2);//longtitude variable
  var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

  var options = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: coords,
    panControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords,
        map: map,
        clickable:true,
        title: "Mevcut Pozisyonunuz : " + enlem + " K " + boylam + " D " + " Koordinat Doğruluğu " + accuracy + " m.dir "
    });

    marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<b>Pozisyonunuz :</b> ' + enlem + ' K ' + boylam + ' D ' +  ' <br><b>Koordinat doğruluğunuz :</b> ' + accuracy + ' m.dir.  </br>'  
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.info.open(map, marker);
    });









}



if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
                            } else {
                                    error('Geo Location is not supported');
                                    }




</script>



</head>
<body onload="success()">



<input type="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right"     value="DEVAM" onClick="window.location.reload()" data-mini="true" />

<div id="mapcontainer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome at SO! But this is not a place where you ask for scripts, please see http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ to find developers who want to script this. You should only ask questions if you need help with some script, see also [ask]

Comment: I think the OP asked a valid question, he's not asking for anybody to do the coding for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but this kind of data processing and storage is usually done through a server-side program, and for good reason.

If all of your application's logic, including security checks and such, is in the javascript code (which any one of your users can read and modify, just by using their browser's developer tools) and if the database is just an online spreadsheet, what stops a malicious user from deleting your entire database, or reading other people's locations, or such?

The point is, you are better off using a server-side language and database technology and do things the traditional way, because it offers more in terms of security and protection for / from various kind of users. PHP and MySQL are by far the most popular choices, although in my opinion there are better languages around, such as Ruby or Python.

---

If, however, you understand the security implications and still wish to build an interactive application using a Google Spreadsheet as its data store, here you will find an introduction and a tutorial on how to do so:

http://www.alatechsource.org/blog/2012/05/using-the-google-spreadsheets-data-api-to-build-a-recommended-reading-list-code-words.h

Comment: Good answer. In particular, you'd need to access the Google spreadsheet with your Google account... assuming you don't want the account info available to everyone using your site, you would definitely want to do this on the server side.

Comment: Especially this application will be a team tracking app. So sharing account info with the participants  won't be a problem. But the general opinion shows me I have to use php and a database. Becouse of having no answer about how to use spreadsheet and also javascript for this purpose, I think I have to use php....

Comment: I improved my answer with an actual pointer on how to do what you ask!